# Help me understand this matrix derivative (for the LS estimation proof)

Tags: matrix-calculus, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to understand this proof of LS estimation, but I've never studied matrix calculus.

I've managed to find a couple of identities on the web and and I see how to get the first part of the derivative. But how do I get the second part ? Is there any recommended source with a simple explanation about matrix calculus ?

Also, what is the meaning of the asterisk ? Is that the complex conjugate left over ?

[image: LS Proof]

Comment: You can also derive the normal equations without calculus. For an optimal choice of $ \hat H$, the residual $ Y-X \hat H $ is orthogonal to the range of $ X $. It follows that $ Y - X \hat H $ is in the null space of $ X^H $.

Answer (score 2):

The asterisk represents the complex conjugate, which is related to the hermitian conjugate and the transpose by $$X^H = (X^*)^T$$

Now consider the Frobenius norm of the matrix $M$, expressed in terms of the [Frobenius (:) inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product), and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \|M\|_F^2 = M^*:M \cr
dJ &= M^*:dM \cr
}$$
Note that for purposes of [differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives), $M^*$ can be considered to be independent of $M$.

Now it's time to substitute $(XH-Y)$ for $M$ 
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= (XH-Y)^*:X\,dH \cr
   &= X^T(XH-Y)^*:dH \cr
   &= (X^HXH-X^HY)^*:dH \cr
}$$
Since $dJ=\Big(\frac{\partial J}{\partial H}:dH\Big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial J}{\partial H} &= (X^HXH-X^HY)^* \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero, and taking the complex conjugate leads to a sytem of linear equations which can be solved for $H$
$$\eqalign{
 X^HXH &= X^HY \cr
 H &= (X^HX)^{-1}X^HY \cr
}$$